# How to add a constant querystring parameter in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a large ASP.NET/C# application that we're currently expanding on. I need to add a querystring parameter to a page and have that parameter be added automatically to every request thereafter.

For example, let's say the user chooses mode=1. I need to add &mode=1 to the querystring of every single link that is clicked from that point forward.  At any point, the user can change the mode=2.  So then I need that change to be reflected on each subsequent request.

And yes, I realize that what I'm basically looking for is to store a flag in either a session variable or a cookie.  However, we've done that and we're having issues with it not persisting correctly.  If nothing else, I'd like to put this in the querystring if only for testing purposes to see if the issue is simply with session/cookie state, or if somewhere in our code it's getting improperly reset.

Comment: Create a string building method with these flags and append it after every link on the page. And realize that this will be more difficult if you have a single form on the page you'll need to POST. But seriously, I would recommend you: Don't focus on this, fix the issues with session and use session.

Comment: Even if you want to continuously add this to the querystring, you're going to need to store it somewhere (session/cookie). I think you'll need to troubleshoot where it is being reset. Are you currently using session or cookies? Are they timing out or expiring?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try and rework this approach as it sounds messy and it likely to cause issues down the track - sessions are perfect for this type of thing.

If you really need to do this I would suggest writing up a http handler to intercept all http requests and make sure these parameters are in included in each request

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001